# Getting Facebook user's public education info

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

If I obtain a Facebook user id using the Graph API, is it possible to access that user's education that he publicly displays on his profile without him giving permission to my app to do so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> If I obtain a Facebook user id using the Graph API, is it possible to access that user's education that he publicly displays on his profile without him giving permission to my app to do so?

No, that is not possible.

Publicly available via the UI, does not automatically mean publicly available via API as well.

The user needs to login to your app and grant it permission to access their education information.